# How to store three fields in ArrayList by using one object using Java code?

Tags: java, xml, collections

I have three fields material, date, quantity. I am getting data by using xpath. These data needs to be stored in single object by using Collections concepts?

```
MbMessage outMessage = outAssembly.getMessage();        
MbElement root = outMessage.getRootElement().getLastChild();

String materialNumber = root.getFirstElementByPath("xpath").getValueAsString();
MbElement reqdateEle = root.getFirstElementByPath("xpath");
String reqdate = reqdateEle.getValueAsString();

MbElement quantityEle = root.getFirstElementByPath("xpath");
String quantity = quantityEle.getValueAsString();

LinkedList<String> object = new LinkedList<String>(); 
object.add(materialNumber);
object.add(reqdate);
object.add(quantity);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

ArrayList<String> object = new ArrayList<>();
object.add(materialNumber);
object.add(reqdate);
object.add(quantity);

map.put("objectName", object);
```